# mod throwing Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

here is my code to find leap years:

```
Select first_name, last_name,birth_date
FROM students
WHERE MOD(year(birth_date),4) =0
AND MOD(year(birth_date),100) =0
AND MOD(year(birth_date),400) =0;
```

but it returns this:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
'MOD(year(birth_date),4) =0
 AND MOD(year(birth_date),100) =0
 AND MOD(year(birth_date),400) =0;
```

and I can't figure out the problem

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Comment: which DBMS ? MySQL, SQL Server etc ?

Comment: OR. Should definitely be OR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from the error statement, you are using `MS ACCESS`.

Syntax for `mod` is:

```
n1 mod n2
```

So, your query becomes (fixed):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,birth_date
FROM students
WHERE year(birth_date) mod 4 = 0
AND (
    NOT year(birth_date) mod 100 = 0
    OR  year(birth_date) mod 400 = 0
);
```

or

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,birth_date
FROM students
WHERE (
    NOT year(birth_date) mod 100 = 0
    AND year(birth_date) mod 4   = 0
)   OR  year(birth_date) mod 400 = 0
;
```

Comment: @Anand - Really? Try it :)

Comment: If ```year(birth_date) mod 400 = 0``` then ```year(birth_date) mod 100``` will always be 0. Just saying :)

Comment: @Anand - and `false or true = true`

Comment: Which would mean that the AND will make it so this condition evaluates to true only every 400 years. Or am I going clinically insane? :)

Comment: @Anand - take example of 1992 -- it's divisble by 4 and not divisble by 100.. so  `true and (true or false) =>  true`

Comment: @Anand - added another version - If you like that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "%"? Just to examine if it's error from mod function, also, specify your DBMS would be helpful too,

> Select first_name, last_name,birth_date
>       FROM students
>       WHERE year(birth_date)%4 =0
>       AND year(birth_date)%100 =0
>       AND year(birth_date)%400 =0;